# How to force vue to wait for async <script> to run before mounting components

Tags: vue.js

I have an async js script which is loaded at the top of index.html in my vue project. This script exposes several functions into the window object which I would like to be able to call. I would like to be able to call these functions in the mounted() lifecycle hook, but the async function appears to complete only after mounted has finished. Is there a way I can force the vue instance to wait for all <script> to complete before mounting the root component?

Answer (score 1):

According to this issue in Github https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7209 it seems that the async hooks in Vue lifecycle `mounted()` `created()` etc, is only for the ability to call async functions.  but the lifecycle itself is synchronous.

Here are some ideas to manage this problem:

1. You can wrap your component with `v-if` and render it just as soon as your data is ready.
2. If you render a component by `router` - you can use the lifecycle of Vue router. and call your async function **before** enter to Vue page. do it like this:

   ```
   export default {
      beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
          // called before the route that renders this component is confirmed.
          next()
      }
   }
   ```

this `next()` function calls the first Vue lifecycle hook...

full tutorial: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards

Answer (score -1):

If anyone is interested, here is how I solved my problem:

I modified the js file that the <script> was referencing to set `global.initComplete=false` initially, and when the script was complete, I marked it as true.

For main.js file, I used:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

function init() {
    let vm = await new Vue({
        render: h => h(App),
    })
    if(!global.initComplete) {
        setTimeout(init, 50)
    } else {
        vm.$mount('#app')
    }
}
init()
```

Comment: Why are you awaiting the Vue constructor? It's not async

Comment: @Phil You're absolutely correct. That was there from a previous attempt I had made at solving the problem.